# Controlling Collisions of Rotated Parent's child-object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm making a first-person game in a hollow-sphere world and moving the player around by making it the child of an object in the center of the world which I then rotate. There are objects inside the sphere that I don't want the player to walk through.

Attaching colliders and rigid bodies causes the player, upon collision with said objects, to become dislocated from the parent and roll off in whatever direction is dictated by collision physics. I would seem to instead need a Trigger instead of a Collider here, but I'm unsure of what directions to feed OnTriggerEnter in order to preserve the player's movement outside of the Trigger, while not allowing it to go further into the Trigger.

So what I need is a way to make sure that the following criteria are fulfilled:

- Parent center-piece and child player-object always remain in their
     original relation.
- Collision with another object prevents rotation of the parent object
     in the direction of said object.

If it's of any help, below is the player script, which is attached to the parent object in the center of the sphere-world.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityStandardAssets.CrossPlatformInput;

public class PlayerController2 : MonoBehaviour
{

    public float XSensitivity = 2f;
    public float YSensitivity = 2f;

    public bool clampVerticalRotation = true;
    public float MinimumX = -90F;
    public float MaximumX = 90F;
    public float speed = 1;
    public bool smooth;
    public float smoothTime = 5f;
    public bool lockCursor = true;
    public bool playerMovement = false;

    private Quaternion m_PlayerTargetRot;
    private Quaternion m_CameraTargetRot;
    private bool m_cursorIsLocked = true;


    private Transform player;

    public Transform cam;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Awake()
    {
        player = GetComponent<Transform>();
        m_PlayerTargetRot = player.localRotation;
        m_CameraTargetRot = cam.localRotation;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

        float xRot = CrossPlatformInputManager.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * YSensitivity; //mouselook, lookrotation()

        float yRot = CrossPlatformInputManager.GetAxis("Mouse X") * XSensitivity;

        if (playerMovement)
        {
            Vector2 input = new Vector2
            {
                x = CrossPlatformInputManager.GetAxis("Horizontal") * speed,
                y = CrossPlatformInputManager.GetAxis("Vertical") * speed
            };



            m_PlayerTargetRot *= Quaternion.Euler(-input.y, yRot, input.x);
        }
        else
            m_PlayerTargetRot *= Quaternion.Euler(0f, yRot, 0f);

        m_CameraTargetRot *= Quaternion.Euler(-xRot, 0.0f, 0.0f);

        if (clampVerticalRotation)
            m_CameraTargetRot = ClampRotationAroundXAxis(m_CameraTargetRot);

        cam.localRotation = Quaternion.Slerp(cam.localRotation, m_CameraTargetRot, smoothTime * Time.deltaTime);
        player.localRotation = Quaternion.Slerp(player.localRotation, m_PlayerTargetRot, smoothTime * Time.deltaTime);

        UpdateCursorLock();
    }

    public void SetCursorLock(bool value)
    {
        lockCursor = value;
        if (!lockCursor)
        {//we force unlock the cursor if the user disable the cursor locking helper
            Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.None;
            Cursor.visible = true;
        }
    }

    public void UpdateCursorLock()
    {
        //if the user set "lockCursor" we check & properly lock the cursos
        if (lockCursor)
            InternalLockUpdate();
    }

    private void InternalLockUpdate()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.Escape))
        {
            m_cursorIsLocked = false;
        }
        else if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))
        {
            m_cursorIsLocked = true;
        }

        if (m_cursorIsLocked)
        {
            Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
            Cursor.visible = false;
        }
        else if (!m_cursorIsLocked)
        {
            Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.None;
            Cursor.visible = true;
        }
    }

    Quaternion ClampRotationAroundXAxis(Quaternion q) //I haven't dissected this yet, but it works... (taken from Unity's "MouseLook.cs") like much of the above.
    {
        q.x /= q.w;
        q.y /= q.w;
        q.z /= q.w;
        q.w = 1.0f;

        float angleX = 2.0f * Mathf.Rad2Deg * Mathf.Atan(q.x);

        angleX = Mathf.Clamp(angleX, MinimumX, MaximumX);

        q.x = Mathf.Tan(0.5f * Mathf.Deg2Rad * angleX);

        return q;
    }
}
```

Comment: Parentrotater: `if child.notColliding { rotate }` and child `ontriggerenter { notColliding = false }` + `ontriggerleave { notColliding = true }` do you think something like that could work?

Comment: @Fredrik Hey, thanks for your answer. But if notColliding = false, then the player can't move, right? And if the player can't move, how can you leave the trigger?

Comment: Well no, I'd have it just disabling the rotation of the parent

Comment: @Fredrik But the way I have it set up now, the child doesn't move on its own, it gets moved around by the the parent's rotation.

Comment: Put this aside for a while and worked on other problems... One idea I have is to have OnTriggerEnter freeze the player movement temporarily and push the player in the direction opposite of that in which she was last moving. I think this would only work if the player initiates the collision. I'd need another algorithm for the case that the object collides with the player.

Comment: I still haven't been able to figure this out, so I'm trying it another way instead: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42957817/smooth-walking-inside-a-sphere